# Return a result set as output param in a sybase stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, sybase, resultset, output-parameter

I have a stored procedure, in which I want to simply store result of a select statement in an output parameter and return that , how can i do that.

I would appreciate if you give me the right syntax of it, since i am new to DB and Sybase specially, that's why i am just giving u a pseudo code for that..

```
 /pseudo code
 create my_proc(in_param i,out_param o1,out_param o2){

 .....other select and insert statements
 .....
 if(xyz=true){
  o1 = select * from emplyees
  }

  return o1,o2

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need output parameters to return result of query, try below code

```
create procedure proc1
(
  @val1 integer
)
as
begin
  select * from emplyees
end
```

Answer (score 0):

/pseudo code

create my_proc(in_param int,out_param1 int out,out_param2 int out)

BEGIN

.....other select and insert statements

if(xyz=true)BEGIN
  select out_param1=e.col1,out_param1=2=e.col2 from emplyees e
  END
END

Modify datatypes accordingly

Thanks,
Gopal